# Why can't I invoke a static method inside the class body?

Tags: python

```
class StaticClass(object):
    words = []
    StaticClass.init()
    
    @staticmethod
    def init(file_name):
        ...
        words.append('word')
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        print('fun')
            

test = StaticClass()
```

The error  message is:

```
StaticClass.init()
NameError: name 'StaticClass' is not defined
```

Why can't I call the static function inside the  class?

I want to use a class to do this and also want users to be able to do:

```
StaticClass.fun()
```

How to achieve the effect?

Comment: You can't use the name of the class in the body of the class like that. If you must initialise `words` as a class attribute using a function, just define the function outside the class. If you just want to bundle some functions, consider writing a module instead of a class.

Comment: The issue with the error is that StaticClass is *not defined in scope* until after all the *statements* in it’s body are executed. That is, class definitions in Python are *executed* and not “definitions” like C# or Java.

Comment: "Why can't I call the static function inside the class?" Because the class has to exist in order to look up its contents, and you're trying to call it during the process of creating it.

Comment: Inside the class body, the methods are still just functions. You should be able to call ``init()`` by itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, then I should define it as an instance function? I hope users can directly use StaticClass.fun(), without first instantiating it explicitly.

Comment: Just to be sure: Does your class actually have any instance state? If not, you are usually better off using a module.

Comment: If `StaticClass.init` has to happen before users can use the `StaticClass.fun`, then call it yourself, at top level, immediately after the `class` definition. Consider also marking it with a leading underscore if users also shouldn't call it again later. If you need information from the user (such as `file_name`), though, you are out of luck. And yeah, *in general* consider carefully why you want to make things static. Classes are a bit janky as namespaces.

Comment: If you want the words to exist on all instances, just define `words = ['word']` directly.

Comment: OK. I will just make it as a module, without using class. Thanks.

Comment: The class *doesn't exist when you are in the class body*. A class body is an executable block of code, the local namespace becomes the namespace of the class object, but that object gets created after the execution of the class block

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I call the static function inside the class?

As said in the comments, `class` bodies are *executed* in Python. It is like a zero-argument function that automatically runs once; then invokes `type`, passing it the class name, bases and a dict of class attributes *from the local variables of that function*; and only *then* assigns the result from `type` (i.e., a class object) to the name.

You can even put logic and other statements in there:

```
import random

# a class that sometimes fails to exist when you import the module.
class spam:
    if __name__ != '__main__':
        1 / random.randrange(3)
    else:
        print("thank you for running this as the main script.")
    def __init__(self):
        # etc.
```

As such, names have to be in scope. *At the time that this code is running* - because it runs immediately and automatically, rather than being delayed like a function - there isn't a `StaticClass` until after this code has completed. Consequently, the code inside can't reference the class itself.

To solve this, simply move the call to the end:

```py
class StaticClass(object):
    words = []
    
    @staticmethod
    def init(file_name):
        ...
        words.append('word')
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        print('fun')

StaticClass.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time the body of the `StaticClass` class is being executed there is no reference to `StaticClass`, it doesn't exist yet. The body of the class is executed inside a namespace which is a dictionary. After that a new instance of type `type` which is here named `StaticClass` is created using that populated dictionary and added to the global namespaces. That's what `class` keyword roughly does in simple form.

Actually I don't know why you want this to work. Others already suggested best ways to deal with it but here is workaround if you want to call staticmethod as an initializer function when the *class* is being created and call it inside the class:

```py
class StaticClass(object):
    words = []

    @staticmethod
    def init(file_name, words=words):
        words.append(file_name)

    init.__get__(init)('word')

    @staticmethod
    def fun():
        print('fun')


test = StaticClass()
StaticClass.fun()
print(StaticClass.words)
```

output:

```
fun
['word']
```

Yes it's really a mess, I just want to make it work to say why it didn't work before. You need to call `init.__get__` because staticmethods are not callable. (I'm in Python 3.9.7) This way you `init` executed when the class is created. Also `words` is not accessible because the scope of the class is not enclosed the scope of the body of `init`, so I use it's reference as default parameter.